# How to use secrets from repo with reusable workflow in GitHub Actions?

Tags: github-actions

We have several repositories with micro services. In separate repository (common) we store reusable workflows which are being called from repositories with services. Steps within workflows are quite common like login to docker registry, login to Hashicorp Vault. So far we are using `secrets:inherit` to pass secrets from micro service to reusable workflow. However in this case we need to duplicate the same secrets between repositories. Is there any way to keep all shared secrets in repository where we store reusable workflow? Using organization secrets in github actions is not an option here as we have +2500 repositories in our organization and our application has around 10 repositories only.

Comment: Organization secrets have been created for that context. But if they aren't an option in your case, I guess you'll unfortunately have to duplicate secrets... :/

Comment: hey @lionheart, how did you implement this? We are currently having the exact same issue, but don't want to use organization secrets?
You are using Fine grained PATs now?